# how set LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean to JpaTransactionManager?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

In oficial documentation of spring [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.java-config) write next:

```
@Bean
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {

    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    factory.setPackagesToScan("com.acme.domain");
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    return factory;
  }

  @Bean
  public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {

    JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
    return txManager;
  }
```

and

> It’s important to create LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean and
>   not EntityManagerFactory directly since the former also participates
>   in exception translation mechanisms besides simply creating
>   EntityManagerFactory.

But when I tried use it I get error:

```
setEntityManagerFactory
(javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory)
in JpaTransactionManager cannot be applied
to
(org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean)
```

it is my imports:

```
import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.DependsOn;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
```

Comment: `entityManagerFactory().getObject()` . Or just inject it as a method argument `transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {...}`.

Comment: I do it getNativeEntityManagerFactory.....tnx. Can you see my another quations about entity id?

Comment: Dont't use that. As stated use getObject instemde.

Comment: It solved my problem in two issues. Both methods return one object

Comment: Still you shouldn't as you are bypassing spring logic and callbacks with potentially weird issues at hand.

Answer (score 11):

Your configuration looks correct. Only change your transactionManager definition as below:

```
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {

  JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
  txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
  return txManager;
}
```

The `getObject()` method return singleton `EntityManagerFactory`.

Answer (score 4):

```
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory 
entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
}
```

Construct your JpaTransactionManager with an EntityManagerFactory coming in as parameter from your @Bean.  Spring will automatically create one from the LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean when needed.  This avoids ever calling the getObject()-method.